# Filter by empty td on jquery data tables

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, datatables, activeadmin

Is it possible to filter by empty value?
This is not working (10 - number of column):

```
dashboard_table.fnFilter '', 10, false, false, false
```

Comment: Do you mean null or empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a regular expression:

```
dashboard_table.fnFilter '^$', 10, true, false, false
```

Or if you want to allow whitespaces:

```
dashboard_table.fnFilter '^\s*$', 10, true, false, false
```